# How to use Fab-Button within Tab-Bar or position tab-buttons

Tags: position, tabbar, ionic4

I would like to float a fab-button half over my ion-tab-bar right in the middle of the bar, but the ion-tab-button (icons) in Ionic-4 get in the way. I have achieved this (limited) using css to float the fab-button over the tab-bar.

This is how it is coming out:

[image]

Is there a way to position the ion-tab-bar ion-tab-buttons where I want them along the ion-tab-bar rather than how Ionic wants to place them i.e. if I place say 3 icons (buttons) on the tab-bar they are placed equally apart so the middle button is in the middle of the tab-bar. This basically gets in the way of where I want to float my fab-button so is it possible to say move 2 of the buttons to the far left and one button over to the far right so there is a nice space in the middle for me to float my fab-button?

This is how I would like to achieve it:

[image]

Or, is there a way to integrate a fab-button as one of the tab-buttons in the tab-bar. I realised the use of a tab-button is to navigate/display content on clicking where-as the fab-button click is to display a list of fab-button-list items so I'm guessing it can't be simply placed inside the tab-bar.

Hope someone can understand what I'm trying to achieve and guide/assist me.

Many thanks

Rowie

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a few more empty tabs in to space them out, eg:

`<ion-tab-button tab="">
    </ion-tab-button>`

If you make 7 tabs total, with the first two as home and paper, the next 4 as empty tabs (from above), and the last as the profile, you should be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open-source custom component `ion-tab-bar-middle-fab`. It uses the slots concept to arrange the tab bar buttons and puts the fab button in the middle-fab slot.

There is a usage example and more information on the npm package page:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion-tab-bar-middle-fab

[image]